# What is the principle underneath method-invocation delegating in ActiveRecord AssociationCollection objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This is a piece of my code:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
end

my_company = Company.first
employees = my_company.employees
puts employees.class
puts employees.methods.include? "create"
puts employees.respond_to? :create
```

output after running above code:

```
Array
false
true
```

Even if I override "employees.method_mising" with an empty method body, the create method still exists and run successfully. I wanna know how activerecord add the "create" method to the "employees" object. With Ruby debugger, I found that the "create" method may be added in class "ActiveRecord::Associations::AssociationCollection", I also have tried to read the source code, but it's too complex to me, I could not find out the principle underneath. So there must be somebody who knows the principle, right? Could you teach me about it?

Answer (score 0):

After reading source code of active_record, I found that the "employees" var is an instance of  class "ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation" (< "ActiveRecord::Associations::AssociationCollection" < "ActiveRecord::Associations::AssociationProxy") actually. In fact, they undef almost any methods(include "methods", "class", etc) in AssociationProxy by adding this line of code:

```
      instance_methods.each { |m| undef_method m unless m.to_s =~ /^(?:nil\?|send|object_id|to_a)$|^__|^respond_to_missing|proxy_/ }
```

and they use a target object(in my case, it's an instance of Array) to delegate the "undef"ed methods, and the "respond_to?", etc methods is delegated to the "proxy" object which has the "create/build" methods.So "employees.respond_to? :create" returns true, but the method list returned by invocation of calling "employees.methods" does not contain the "create" method.